# Rstrudio Converting large CSV to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently working on a project for RNA-Seq analysis. I have to convert a file comparing 11 samples by the number of reads for about three thousand genes (basically 11 rows and 3000 ish columns).

I want to convert the excel data to a data frame, but for some reason, the data.matrix that I create only contains the first 15 genes rather than the 3000 in the file. To create my dataframe, I am converting the xlsx to csv and then using as.data.frame(read.csv()) in Rstudio to create my data frame. Does anyone know how to fix this so that all the rows are being used?

Comment: If you are reading a csv file vroom is usually faster, but what is probably happening is that  your data is not on the first sheet in excel, try to mess around with the readxl function read_excel, another common problem is that you need to skip some rows

Comment: vroom worked for me. Thank you kind stranger!!

Comment: No problem, good luck!